# why System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, csv, streamreader

I have write the code below, when i run it, it says

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: L'index is outof the limites of table.
   in AddWindowsForm.MyForm.ReadCSV(StreamReader str) ind:\weiweiwang\signalisationferroviaire\visual studio 2012\projects\addwindowsform1213\addwindowsform1213\myform.h:line 7738
   in AddWindowsForm.MyForm.OpenFileDialogCSV_FileOk(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e) in d:\weiweiwang\signalisationferroviaire\visual studio 2012\projects\addwindowsform1213\addwindowsform1213\myform.h:line 7728
   in System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.OnFileOk(CancelEventArgs e)
   in System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.HandleVistaFileOk(IFileDialog dialog)
```

I don't understand why...

```
private: System::Void OpenFileDialogCSV_FileOk(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::CancelEventArgs^  e) {
            InitialiserDonnees(); 
            strFileDirectoryName=OpenFileDialogCSV->InitialDirectory+OpenFileDialogCSV->FileName;
            StreamReader ^strReadFile=gcnew StreamReader (strFileDirectoryName);
            String ^strL="";            
            MyForm::Text="Aide aux calculs des distances:" + System::IO::Path::GetFileName(OpenFileDialogCSV->FileName);
            ReadCSV(strReadFile);           
         }



public: void ReadCSV ( StreamReader ^str)   
        {
            array<String^>^temp=gcnew array <String^> {"","","","","","","","","","",""};
            String ^strL="";
            //Read Info Poste et track
                    strL=str->ReadLine();
                    strL=str->ReadLine();
                    temp=strL->Split(';');
                    textBoxNomPoste->Text=temp[1];

                    strL=str->ReadLine();
                    temp=strL->Split(';');
                    textBoxNomVoie2->Text=temp[1];

                    strL=str->ReadLine();
                    temp=strL->Split(';');
                    comboBoxImpairPair->Text=temp[1];

                    strL=str->ReadLine();
                    temp=strL->Split(';');
                    ComboBoxNbDeclivite->Text=temp[1];
}
```

Comment: Is that your original error message? It looks like someone is writing with a french accent.

Comment: In fact, i use visual studio in french version... :)

Answer (score 1):

The `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` exception indicates that you are accessing an array or container with an invalid index. That is the index refers to an item that does not exist. In the code, you use array indexing when you access the `temp` array. You attempt to access item with index 1 here:

```
temp[1]
```

The error is informing you that `temp` does not contain an item with index 1.

You assigned `temp` here:

```
temp=strL->Split(';');
```

Clearly the result of this call to `Split()` is an array with fewer than 2 elements. Inspect the content of `strL` to understand why this is so.

Note that this line of code:

```
array<String^>^temp=gcnew array <String^> {"","","","","","","","","","",""};
```

is utterly pointless because you never read the value of `temp` before assigning a different value.

Comment: I've no idea. I don't know what you are trying to do. Ask yourself why the string values that you split don't have any semi colons. Remember that you asked why your code was failing. That question is what I answered.

Comment: in fact, i want to read a file csv (ReadCSV(strReadFile);), normaly the content of this file is in "strReadFile", then i call the function ReadCSV and put all the content in the "str", then "ReadLine()" can read the content line by line. i use also  array temp to read the string of each line one by one. thank you for your help!

Comment: So, is your question answered?

Comment: non, i don't know how to resolve this problem, how to modify the code

Comment: That's different. That's the solution to your problem. We cannot help there because we don't know the problem, or have the input data. We can just answer the question that you asked. Are you struggling with understanding the answer? How can I help more?